# Moodle - move QR code from profile to login page

Tags: php, html, plugins, qr-code, moodle

I'm trying to move the QR code block to the main login page, i don't want to use the QR code to login, just the download app QR code generated on the profile page, i seems that the only way is via code insert but i'm not very sure how to do it because i can't find either the code or the function related to the img generation, i looked at the profile.php page on my moodle and it seems that it is created by the function:

```
  echo $OUTPUT->custom_block_region('content');
```

but this function looks like is related to all the profile fields instead of just the QR code block, i'm trying to find some code or function related to it but no success until so i'm asking if someone knows if it is possible to put the "download app QR code" block on the login and how to do it.

Comment: it seems like its actually rendered in                                                                                                    $renderer = $PAGE->get_renderer('core_user', 'myprofile');

Comment: $tree = core_user\output\myprofile\manager::build_tree($user, $currentuser);

Comment: echo $renderer->render($tree);

Comment: one of these lines calls the renderer from the profile page and it seems that the qr code is executed from one of those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile QR code section renderer from the component tool_mobile.

you can find the QR code image generation method on the function **tool_mobile_myprofile_navigation** in "*YourMoodle\admin\tool\mobile\lib.PHP*"

You can generate the QR code to access the mobile app using the below code.

```
$mobilesettings = get_config('tool_mobile');
$qrcodeimg = tool_mobile\api::generate_login_qrcode($mobilesettings);
$qrcodeforappstr = get_string('qrcodeformobileappaccess', 'tool_mobile');

echo html_writer::div(html_writer::img($qrcodeimg, $qrcodeforappstr));
```

If you want to add this QR code to the login page. You can do it by rendering the login page using the theme (recommended). Or you can do it by modifying the core.

Render by theme.

In your boost theme core_renderer.php file. Please add the below function in the core_renderer class to render the login page.
you can find the core_renderer file in "*Moodle\theme\boost\classes\output\core_renderer.php*"

```
public function render_login(\core_auth\output\login $form) {
    global $CFG, $SITE;

    $context = $form->export_for_template($this);

    // Override because rendering is not supported in template yet.
    if ($CFG->rememberusername == 0) {
        $context->cookieshelpiconformatted = $this->help_icon('cookiesenabledonlysession');
    } else {
        $context->cookieshelpiconformatted = $this->help_icon('cookiesenabled');
    }
    $context->errorformatted = $this->error_text($context->error);
    $url = $this->get_logo_url();
    if ($url) {
        $url = $url->out(false);
    }
    $context->logourl = $url;
    $context->sitename = format_string($SITE->fullname, true,
            ['context' => \context_course::instance(SITEID), "escape" => false]);
    // QR Code to access the site URL in mobile app.
    $mobilesettings = get_config('tool_mobile');
    $qrcodeimg = \tool_mobile\api::generate_login_qrcode($mobilesettings);
    $qrcodeforappstr = get_string('qrcodeformobileappaccess', 'tool_mobile');
    
    $context->qrcodeimage = \html_writer::div(\html_writer::img($qrcodeimg, $qrcodeforappstr));

    return $this->render_from_template('core/loginform', $context);
}
```

Then create the folder "**core**" in your boost theme templates folder.

Then copy the loginform.mustache file from Moodle\lib\templates\loginform.mustache to the folder "**core**" which is created in your boost theme templates folder.

And add the code `{{{qrcodeimage}}}` in the copied loginform.mustache file.

Comment: thanks a lot, i've learning moodle for 1 month now but this part was very hard to discorver.